# While loops and sockets

Tags: java, sockets, while-loop

I'm trying to make a networking application, for a proof of concept project.
I need to keep the connection open, the joined clients, but the while loop I'm running never gets out of the first loop.
Code:

```
public class comm implements Runnable {

    private Socket socket;
    private String line, input;
    boolean sending = true;
    boolean connected = false;
    private int me;
    private BufferedReader br;
    private PrintWriter pw;

    doComms(Socket server) {
       socket = server;
        me = Main.connected;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

            while (true) {

                System.out.println("Waiting");
                readCommand();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }

    private void readCommand() throws Exception {

        String str;

        while (br.readLine() != null) {

            if (!connected) {
                pw.println("connect");
            }

            str = br.readLine();
            System.out.println(str);

            if (str.startsWith("!START!")) {
                System.out.println("User connected");
                connected = true;
                String[] split = str.split("#");
                Main.jTable1.getModel().setValueAt(split[1], me, 2);
                Main.jTable1.getModel().setValueAt(split[2], me, 3);
                Main.jTable1.getModel().setValueAt("Connected...", me, 4);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Starting that code is fine, all it does is makes a new thread for each connected users, and the client software runs fine too. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Inside run() method you have written while (true), which is not correct.

Comment: But, I want the code to loop, so I can add more communications between the client and server.

Comment: First loop as in the one with `true` ?

Comment: Are you getting any exeption?

Comment: First loop as in the first loop of the `while(true)` it never breaks the loop.

Comment: It's not supposed to break - when you have `while(true)` it will run for ever. Just have it as a variable and change the value to `false` when you want to break it. I hope this is what you asked.

Comment: No, thats not what I meant, by break, I meant exit the loop, and start it over.

Comment: add `Sysout` to the end of `readCommand()` in the first `while` loop. Then debug and see if it arrives there.

Answer (score 3):

My best guess.  It never gets out of the first readCommand call because readCommand itself is in an infinite loop:

```
 while (br.readLine() != null) {
```

br.readLine will block until the next line from the socket input arrives.  So the only way for the loop to exit is for the remote client to disconnect.

Answer (score 0):

> But the while loop I'm running never gets out of the first loop.

The first loop you are referring to is:

```
while(true) { ... }
```

This will never exit because `true` is always true.

Comment: You mis-understood me.
I mean, exit the loop, and run the code again, it only run the code once.

Comment: Then it's because the br.readline() never returns.  You've made it infinitely run over the socket connection, which is never closed.. EDIT: Oh, looks like someone got that in an answer already (=